# Why initialization of new Long Wrapper with int literal is valid?

Tags: java, initialization, long-integer

Looking at the Java Doc for Long, it only has two constructors:

```
    1) primitive long as param --> new Long(10L);  
    2) String as param --> new Long("23");
```

But this works
new Long(23);

But if the literal is more than the int MAX VALUE (2147483647), the L suffix becomes mandatory so this: (
new Long(2147483648) will now require an L after the value

However:
new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1) is OK

Who can explain this?

Comment: The implicit conversion from `int` to `long` is one of the [*widening primitive conversions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your question is straightforward: passing `int` where `long` is required is allowed because any number that can be represented as an `int` can also be represented as a `long`. This is a so-called *widening conversion*.

The second part, about `new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)`, is trickier. Although the widening conversion occurs here as well, it is not of the value that one might think: if you run this program

```
Long x = new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
System.out.println(x);
```

you get `-2147483648`, not the expected `2147483648`, because of `int` overflowing on addition ([demo](http://ideone.com/eBzqdJ)).

The compiler is not smart enough to promote parts of the expression to `long` *before* performing addition. Widening conversion occurs after the addition has been performed, on the result of the addition with an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening primitive conversion from an integral type to another integral type, or from float to double in a strictfp expression (§15.4), does not lose any information at all; the numeric value is preserved exactly.

The integer value `23` can be converted to long `23L` without loss of any information at all. Thus with the use of through *widening primitive conversions*, JVM implicitly converts it to `23L`.

So when you call

```
new Long(23)
```

It becomes

```
new Long(23L)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we write `new Long(23)` , you can think of it as something like the following happening :

```
int i = 23;
long l = i; // widening primitive conversion
Long newLong = new Long(l);
```

Widening conversions are allowed as per the [JLS 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) , so there are no issues with it.

When we try instead , `new Long(2147483648)` , the first step itself fails, as the value is more than what can fit in an `int`

```
 int i = 2147483648;  // doesn't fit in int
```

When we try `new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)`, you can think of it as something like the following happening:

```
 int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1; // This gives the INTEGER.MIN_VALUE -2147483648
 long l = i ; // widening primitive conversion
 Long newLong = new Long(l);
```

So, this is allowed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The differences come from using literal or not.

By using a literal,

```
long1 = new Long(2147483648)
```

The code will not compile as the compiler checks the validity of the literal again the type of the variable that receives the literal value and `2147483648` is out of range for an `int`.
 So the compiler emits an error.

It is valid for any literal.
As the [compiler expects to have a specific type as value of the literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.1), so it does the check :

The type of a literal is determined as follows:

> The type of an integer literal (§3.10.1) that ends with L or l is long
>   (§4.2.1).
>
> The type of any other integer literal is int (§4.2.1).
>
> ...

By using a computation :

```
long1 = new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
```

the compiler doesn't check if the size of the `Long` argument constructor is in the `int` range.
It is not a literal declaration.
At runtime, an `int` to `long` widening primitive conversion occurs.

It produces so a `int` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` that is `-2147483648` (overflow of `int`) that is converted to a `long` value.